# Check if object with specific value exists in List

Tags: c#, list, find, contains

i am trying to check if a specific object exists in a List. I have ListA, which contains all the Elements, and i have a string, which may or may not belong to the id of one object in List A.

I know the following:

`List<T>.Contains(T)` returns true if the element exists in the List. Problem: I have to search for a specific Element.

`List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>)` returns an Object if it finds an element in the List which has the predicate. Problem: This gives me an object, but i want true or false.

Now i came up with this:

`if (ListA.Contains(ListA.Find(a => a.Id == stringID)) ==true)` ...do cool shit

is this the best solution? Seems kind of odd to me.

Comment: I did, as  a matter of fact i did quite some heavy searching (I always do) but all i could find was Find(), FindIndexOf, Contains etc. Thats how i created the Code i showed.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+list+find+bool

Comment: I searched for stuff like "c# list check if object exists" and didnt find anything. Maybe i would have if i had gone to page 2 or 3 of the results but seriously, who does shit like that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Any()`,

> `Any()` from Linq, finds whether any element in the list satisfies given
> condition or not, If satisfied then return `true`

```
if (ListA.Any(a => a.Id == stringID))
{
    // Your logic goes here
}
```

MSDN : [Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you very much, and thanks to the other people who posted this answer too!

Answer (score 3):

Using .Any is the best option: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```
if(ListA.Any(a => a.Id == stringID))
{
    //You have your value.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Any` for this.

```
if (ListA.Any(item => item.id == yourId))
{
   ...
}
```